# Use cases and user stories in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, scrum, use-case, user-stories

In a SCRUM Agile project we use TFS 2010/VS2010.

In the period before starting this project, the customer has already written out 80% of all the use cases. The issue is that most of these UCs are so large, that I want to split them up in user stories. The user stories can be compared to scenarios for the use cases.

My plan is now use the Agile process template and start creating top level user stories as use cases. Each top level use case will have 1 or more user stories as child beneath the parent user story. Then below the 2nd level user story I add one or more tasks where developers can do their checkin against.

Is this the right approach ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, the proof is that when you create a child work item from a User Story only two types are available: Task and User Story.

[image]

This is made to split big User Stories into a subset of smaller ones.